# Writting a self published book containg many glossy pictures

Tags: self-publishing

I am putting together a fun facts book and my computer (HP office jet 500 series) graphic designs which are mostly colorful preferably glossy. What kind of paper should I use for my regular print and what paper for my designs? I will be self publishing a spiral spin book but do not know what paper should be used for the cover. I am thinking about laminating the cover itself. Any suggestions? JK

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about writing or a related field, as detailed in the [help center](http://writers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming yours is an inkjet printer. (If it isn't specify the exact model.)

Unless you are only going to print one or two copies (in which case buy photo paper for the colour pages and heavy, ordinary paper for the others) you are much better to print on a colour laser printer and use reasonable quality paper (e.g. 80 gram or above). The print will be clearer, the pictures will be much better, you can (with care) print on both sides, and it will be much quicker and cheaper.

Consider using a print on demand service if you are going to print more than a few copies.